# Googlesheet : ARRAYFORMULA with CONCATENATE

Tags: google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Any one can help with to see what was wronng in the picture B, we want the result as picture A but when i change formular with Arrayformlas it is not working.

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `&` instead of `CONCATENATE`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A:A),A:A&B:B,""))
```

[image]